# Padding vs Margin Messing up Alignment?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am designing a theme in Ghost and have encountered a problem that I can't find the solution for. I've given this problem a few hours already and perhaps I am not searching for the right terms so any help would be appreciated:

I have a div wrapping a main tag, and there is a nav bar on top that the wrapper div should clear, things appear to work when I use `margin-top` to clear the nav bar:

[image]

As you can see, the main tag is aligned with the content section of the wrapper div (.wrapper_alex).

However, if I use `padding-top` instead of `margin-top` (with the same value of 101.235px), I get this:

[image]

You see here that the main tag's content and the content of the wrapper div is not aligned. The vertical spacing that has been introduced is circled above with red. It should be noted that main does not have any padding, border, or margin, so I expected it to be aligned.

Any idea what is happening here?

Thanks so much for helping.

Edit 1:

CSS property of main in both cases:

[image]

Edit 2:

```
  <div role='banner' class="header_alex">


  <h5 class="blogtitle_alex">
    <a title="Portfolio" href='http://localhost:2368'>
      Portfolio
    </a>
  <!-- Funky formatting below is for getting rid of space between inline-block elements introduced by whitespace/newlines i.e h5 is purposefully not closed off and only closed off in navigation-->
  </h5
      ><a title="Projects" href='/projects/' class="header_tab_alex">
      Projects
    </a
    ><a title="Travels" href='/travels/' class="header_tab_alex">
      Travels
    </a
    ><a title="About" href='/about/' class="header_tab_alex">
      About
    </a
>

</div>
  <div class="wrapper_alex">

<main class="main_alex" role="main">
    <article class="article_alex" role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <header class="postheader_alex">
    <h1 class="posttitle_alex" itemprop="headline"><a href="/building-my-portfolio/" rel="bookmark">Building My Portfolio!</a></h1>
    <time class="date_alex" datetime="2016-07-01" itemprop="datePublished">Friday 01 Jul 2016</time>
    </header>
      <div class="postcontent_alex" itemprop="articleBody">
      <p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Ghost-Logo.svg" alt="" />
blah blah blah blog post stuff </p>
      </div>
    </article>
</main>
  </div>
```

Edit 3:

Here is the code that moves the wrapper down to clear the nav bar.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setupFixedNav();
  $(window).resize(function () {
    setupFixedNav();
  });
});

function setupFixedNav() {
  $('.wrapper_alex').css('margin-top',$('.header_alex').outerHeight(true));
  //Doesn't work
  //$('.wrapper_alex').css('padding-top',$('.header_alex').outerHeight(true));
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without any code, but I'd bet your heading has margin-top and it collapses with wrapper's margin-top. Also, why 101.235px??)

Comment: Please show the CSS rules of `<main>` in both cases.  By the way what's the problem you're trying to solve? If `padding-top` gives you what you want, why are you messing around with `margin-top`?

Comment: @BeetleJuice showed the CSS rules of main in edit.

Comment: @AntonPudikov the heading has no margin-top property, it has margin-left, margin-right, and margin-bottom. It does, however, have padding-top.

Comment: I added code, and to respond to why 101.235 px: look at Edit 3, where the clearance is calculated by jQuery.

Comment: What is it you actually are asking? ... And post a minimal, working code snippet that reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Ipbug I don't believe that there's no margin-top anywhere on the branch article -> header -> h1

Comment: It must be due to the margin-top on one of the element. And if there is no CSS code, it is impossible for us to find the reason.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will work on reproducing the issue in a small snippet tonight on fiddle.js. I'm away from my computer but will post CSS as soon as I'm back (beware, it is written in LESS). Also, I'll check for margin-top in those elements.

Comment: You guys are right, the margin-top of the <h1> post_title element was messing up the alignment. I am quite surprised this can happen as I expect child elements of the <div> to stay within that <div>. Is it because margin is not considered part of <h1> (I've read margins are considered "outside" the element) that that happens?

Comment: It's a specific behaviour. Very important one. You can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing